# Why did my reputation go down by 15 points?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

Looking at my activity page and also the reputation tab under my profile, I cannot seem to see why my rep went down by 15 points today.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, I presume? http://stackoverflow.com/users/1117

Comment: Yep, I would of specified, but I thought this site was specifically for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Someone probably unaccepted one of your answers.

Comment: ... and it will not notify you of such an event. It simply "deletes" the event from the database and rep is changed accordingly.

Comment: I assumed this was the case, but I figured it would have notified me.  Oh well, I guess I will try to figure out which answer it was.

Comment: Had this happen to me today too. Kind of annoying that there's no notification, or even an audit trail in your "Activity" list.

Comment: Happened to me too. In my case it was because a question was moved to another site. The great thing was that I gained +15 on the other site! Yeah, first point! ;-)
But it would be nice if you got a notification and didn't have to look why it happened.